# Is there a workaround to make the Raspberry Pi 4 output 1.8 V?

Tags: pi-4, spi, voltage

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B and I want to use it to flash a Coreboot BIOS image to a SPI EEPROM chip (using either flashrom or a program called "[spi flash programmer](https://github.com/nfd/spi-flash-programmer)" that is originally made for Arduino). The SPI chip is a W25Q64FW Winbond Chip which is soldered to a Packard Bell EasyNote Laptop with an Acer NB.Y4311.002 motherboard. The chip expects a voltage of 1.8V.
Adding pullup resistors to create an external level shifter is not only complicated, but also created a bottle neck for the reading and writing speed of the `spi flash programmer` program (taking more than 2 hours each time) and negatively influenced the signal quality as shown on the oscilloscope.

Is there any workaround (also weird/rare ones) to make the Raspberry Pi directly output 1.8 V for the SPI chip?
I am happy about any hint.

Edit: A unidirectional connection is ok.
Regarding the speed, we want to transfer a BIOS image about 8 Mebibytes big. I suppose anything up to 30 min would be acceptable to work with. (We sometimes have to rely on try-and-error, which is hard if every try needs several hours.)

Answer (score 2):

#### You indicated "hints" were OK, so here's a `hint-but-not-an-answer`:

I *suspect* that there is a way to get 1.8V out of the RPi 4B - but this is only a suspicion. I only read of it a day or two ago, and I've not tried it, nor explored the idea in any detail. The *basis* for my suspicion may be found in the [CM4 datasheet](http://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/cm4/cm4-datasheet.pdf). Reference **para 3.3 Electrical Specification:**

> Please note that Vref is the GPIO bank voltage which must be tied to either 3.3V or 1.8v rail.

Note that the [CM4 module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/compute-module-4/?variant=raspberry-pi-cm4001000) is a **different** platform than the RPi 4B. However, it uses the very same **BCM2711** SoC as the RPi 4B, and the ["official documentation" on GPIO](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/gpio/README.md) specifically refers us to the CM4 Datasheet for details on the GPIO voltage specifications. Or, perhaps it may be necessary to purchase a CM4 and associated [CM4 IO board](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/compute-module-4-io-board/) to get at this?

Of course, it is entirely possible that I've not properly translated the "official documentation" into [proper English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_English)  :)  If no one here in RPi SE suggests anything more substantial, you might post an "Issue" on the [RPi firmware GitHub site](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/new) - some of the staff are very helpful.

If it turns out that my `hint-but-not-an-answer` is rubbish, then I have one other answer that is very likely more substantial:

#### A real answer:

I have wasted enormous amounts of time attempting to configure RPi hardware using the tools provided by The Foundation - `/boot/config.txt`, [rpi-eeprom bootloader configuration](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711_bootloader_config.md) and so forth. I believe this is due in large part to my background - I am more comfortable with systems ruled by physical laws than man-made (e.g. software) laws. I say all of this only to underscore that a *hardware solution* may be a more time-efficient solution.

A potentially straightforward solution to your problem may be to use a [level-shifter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_shifter). You're likely familiar with these devices, but here's a [brief intro written by TI](https://www.ti.com/logic-circuit/voltage-level-translation/overview.html). This link may suggest some [specific TI part numbers](https://www.ti.com/sitesearch/docs/universalsearch.tsp?langPref=en-US&searchTerm=spi%20level%20shifter&nr=1444#q=spi%20level%20shifter&t=everything&linkId=1) that meet your specifications.

One final point: The majority of ICs produced today are in *surface-mount* packages, and these are not particularly easy-to-use for hobbyists. If you have the inclination, and basic soldering skills, there are generic "breakout boards" for many common SM packages, and if not several vendors will sell you a customised breakout board tailored to a specific IC.

Answer (score 0):

The GPIO on the Pi4 is 3.3V.

You will need some external circuitry but without more details it is impossible to suggest what.

It is simple to convert voltage levels - the complexity depends on speed requirements and whether unidirectional or bidirectional is needed.

Comment: Which kind of details should I add to my question, in order to make this more "answerable"?

Comment: speed requirements and whether unidirectional or bidirectional also detail of what you want to connect. This is not Pi specific - it is an EE Question. If "Adding pullup resistors to create an external level shifter is … complicated" you won't get enything simpler.